# Jquery click event not firing on appended element

Tags: jquery

This is driving me insane. I am adding rows to a table after the page is loaded. There is one button to remove the row and one button to save it to a database. After adding a new row, I can remove it just fine using a click event. However, when adding a row and trying to traverse it to get access to the previous input, I'm getting nothing. Not certain what I am doing wrong.

Ideally, when I click on the save button, it would display the value of the previous which is: `<input class="box2"  type="text" value="test">`, so I'm expecting to see "test"

HTML

```
<input id="addChatQuestion" type="button" value="Add Row"> 

<table>
<tbody id="mainBody" class="questionBody"> 
<tr>
    <td> <input class="box1" type="text" value="4"> <input class="box2" type="text" value="Not Void"> <input class="qSave" type="button" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('#addChatQuestion').click(function() {
var newRow ='<tr><td><input class="box1" type="text" value="" /> <input class="box2"  type="text" value="test"> <input class="qSave" type="button" value="Save"><input class="qDelete" type="button" value="Delete"></td></tr>';
$('#mainBody').append(newRow);
});

$('.questionBody').on('click', '.qSave', function() {
var score = $(this).prev().val();
alert(score);
});

$('.questionBody').on('click', '.qDelete', function() {
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2Sy2/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, even the posted fiddle.

Comment: @adeneo only on your pc it works?

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me as well. What are you seeing instead of "test"?

Comment: @GertB. - Maybe I'm special! Seriously, it alerts just fine, and removes just fine, and I don't see why it wouldn't ?

Comment: Looks like I forgot a period before qSave. Probably should have realized that after I added it when posting this question. Just thought I removed it while formatting the code. Apparently not. Thanks guys, forgive my tired eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to click on the save button listed below, and have it alert the one above as drawn?

[image: Sample]

If you are instead expecting to see `test` in your `alert`, the system is working as intended.

### I have:

- Created 10 elements
- Removed 5 of them
- Added 3 more
- Tested every value and the corresponding `test` `alerts` every time.